# Unable to read or fetch nested elements/text from the GML file using Python

Tags: python, xml, gml, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am trying to read the **.GML** file and want to fetch the co-ordinates from the `<gml:posList>` tag. I am not able to do it.

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<os:FeatureCollection xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:os="http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:oml="http://namespaces.os.uk/open/oml/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" gml:id="OSOpenMapLocal" xsi:schemaLocation="http://namespaces.os.uk/open/oml/1.0 https://ordnancesurvey.co.uk/xml/open/oml/1.0/OSOpenMapLocal.xsd">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
            <gml:lowerCorner>390000 1130000</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>400000 1150000</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <os:metadata xlink:href="http://www.os.uk/xml/products/OML.xml"/>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="idEA5BECB9-B5EC-40A7-87F2-FFE7BACCD4C6">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="idEA5BECB9-B5EC-40A7-87F2-FFE7BACCD4C6-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>397291.02 1138758.65 397282 1138766.94 397278.95 1138763.63 397287.97 1138755.34 397291.02 1138758.65</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="idD50A8852-CE5F-4DFC-93E8-2B876D6E3FD4">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="idD50A8852-CE5F-4DFC-93E8-2B876D6E3FD4-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>397408.26 1138885.87 397398.45 1138886.03 397398.33 1138878.94 397408.14 1138878.78 397408.26 1138885.87</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id900D7042-EF0D-4900-93FB-C9049C5A0E98">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id900D7042-EF0D-4900-93FB-C9049C5A0E98-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>397439.25 1138892.27 397425.68 1138897.42 397421.71 1138886.96 397435.28 1138881.81 397439.25 1138892.27</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id908A62CC-ADE7-4B44-9459-FCE0555989FD">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id908A62CC-ADE7-4B44-9459-FCE0555989FD-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>397435.85 1139053.06 397423.74 1139045.31 397427.43 1139039.54 397439.54 1139047.29 397435.85 1139053.06</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id5BA3AE25-F67B-414F-B130-3D12B41D0005">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id5BA3AE25-F67B-414F-B130-3D12B41D0005-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>397437.52 1138900.13 397442.08 1138911.18 397437.39 1138913.12 397432.83 1138902.07 397437.52 1138900.13</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id3FB22189-2930-4098-814A-88FB0A3A1555">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id3FB22189-2930-4098-814A-88FB0A3A1555-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>396545.45 1136429.42 396545.31 1136422.76 396549.2 1136422.68 396549.34 1136429.34 396545.45 1136429.42</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="idE681433D-9934-4CD9-B503-1142384D5246">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="idE681433D-9934-4CD9-B503-1142384D5246-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>396502.52 1136798.79 396491.61 1136800.1 396491.19 1136796.63 396502.11 1136795.32 396502.52 1136798.79</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id81E51D80-0DBA-46BC-B12B-F4550025CBB2">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id81E51D80-0DBA-46BC-B12B-F4550025CBB2-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>396298.76 1137049.65 396292.52 1137039.78 396298.5 1137036 396304.74 1137045.88 396298.76 1137049.65</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="idF509D605-3102-49FC-89B1-36C8E210C83A">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="idF509D605-3102-49FC-89B1-36C8E210C83A-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>396275 1137043 396283.5 1137055.5 396278.69 1137058.77 396270.19 1137046.27 396275 1137043</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
    <os:featureMember>
        <oml:Building gml:id="id6E040C7E-E534-46B9-877B-39165715B400">
            <oml:geometry>
                <gml:Surface gml:id="id6E040C7E-E534-46B9-877B-39165715B400-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700" srsDimension="2">
                    <gml:patches>
                        <gml:PolygonPatch>
                            <gml:exterior>
                                <gml:LinearRing>
                                    <gml:posList>396298.56 1137058.27 396295.06 1137071.27 396288.5 1137069.5 396292 1137056.5 396298.56 1137058.27</gml:posList>
                                </gml:LinearRing>
                            </gml:exterior>
                        </gml:PolygonPatch>
                    </gml:patches>
                </gml:Surface>
            </oml:geometry>
            <oml:featureCode>15014</oml:featureCode>
        </oml:Building>
    </os:featureMember>
</os:FeatureCollection>
```

**Below is my code (Just trying to get the root as first step):**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

data = et.parse("HT.gml")
root = data.getroot()
print(root)
```

**Output:**
`<Element '{http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0}FeatureCollection' at 0x0000018838AE82C0>`

Even the output is incorrect. Could anyone please let me know how to extract data from .GML file?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that the output of `data.getroot()` is incorrect? It seems to be correct per your example.

Comment: Because root should be ```<os:FeatureCollection ...``` the 2nd line from the sample. Why it has only showed ```<Element '{http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0}FeatureCollection'```?

Comment: That's how namespaces work in XML. `os:` is an alias for the full URL, which is `http://namespaces.os.uk/product/1.0`. You can see the namespace declarations in the attributes that start with `xmlns:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the content of the `posList` tags, you can do something simple like this:

```py
result = []
for el in root.iter():
     if el.tag == '{http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}posList':
         results.append(el.text)
print(result)
```

If you want to filter by particular tags or more complicated paths, the easiest way is to create an XPath query. For the case you asked in the comments (all `posList`s inside `oml:Building`), you can do like this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

data = et.parse("HT.gml")
root = data.getroot()

xpath_query = './/{http://namespaces.os.uk/open/oml/1.0}Building//{http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}posList'

result = []
for el in root.findall(xpath_query):
    result.append(el.text)
print(result)
```

Note that you have to give the full namespace of the tag (`gml` is not part of the name of the tag, it is just an alias for the actual namespace, which is a URI). The URI of each alias is in the root element, in the attributes that look like `xmlns:alias`.

Comment: How do I get ```posList``` of only a particular tag? For example, if I want to get ```posList``` of only ```<oml:Building``` and no other feature member then how do I filter it? Assuming it is a nested structure. Note: The given .GML file is only a sample. It has lot of other feature members.

Comment: @ManishShegokar, I updated the answer with an example answering your question in the comment. If you find this adequate, please update your question with this request to make it more complete.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code! I have updated my question asking the same.